# Java compilation fail with method reference but works with lambda

Tags: java, generics, java-8, method-reference

We're trying to add an overloaded `collect` method to our extended Java Stream API which we're currently defining as:

```
interface ExtendedStream<R> extends Stream<R> {

   <R1> R1 collect(SerializableSupplier<Collector<? super R, ?, R1>> supplier);

}
```

`SerializableSupplier` is define as just:

```
interface SerializableSupplier<T> extends Serializable, Supplier<T> {
}
```

Calling this collect method with a lambda works fine, but calling it with a method reference fails to compile with errors such as:

```
Error:(50, 72) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R1,capture#1 of ?,T
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
      java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<T>> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>,?,R1>)
```

I've created a standalone Java class [here](https://gist.github.com/galderz/a44468018e5ecd270fd7e0e28db5b499) which you can load into your compiler to try it out.

I'm currently using Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Is this is a bug or some error in how we're defining things?

**NOTE**: I get this compilation error both from IntelliJ and when compiling with Maven. I don't use Eclipse.

Cheers,
Galder

Comment: You should include all the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: The code, which you can fully run standalone, is about 400 lines. Are you asking to paste the 400 lines? Doesn't sound like a good idea :\

Comment: If the whole 400 lines are necessary in order to find the problem, then yes, that's what you should do. However, it is much more likely you can post much shorter code that shows your problem - the lambda expression that works and the method reference that doesn't work.

Comment: Eugene, have you tried running it? It has a main() function.

Comment: 1) I can't tell that you added a comment, unless you annotate me with `@`, like `@Eugene`... 2) totally my bad - it works fine with `Eclipse Oxygen` and `javac 9`; but indeed fails for `javac 8`

Comment: I've added a note to the summary. I don't use Eclipse, but I get this error both with IntelliJ and when compiling it via Maven.

Comment: A `Collector` doesn’t become serializable, just because you let a serializable `Supplier` return it. I’m afraid, you’re going to waste a lot of time trying something that will lead you to nowhere…

Comment: @Holger *still* this looks like a bug to me, it should work, there is nothing *too*  fancy going on here... but it is a nightmare finding it, I'm still trying

Comment: are you sure that you need a definition `Collector<? super T, ?, R1>>` in `collect` instead of `Collector<T, ?, R1>`. this seems to be the problem here (I still can't find the relevant `lower bound` bug, *I think*)...

Comment: @Eugene: well, yes, and I’m not surprised that there’s another bug (or another symptom of an already known bug), but since you state, that Java 9 has already fixed it, there’s not much worth thinking too much about it. Inserting an explicit type, like `.collect(Collectors::<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>toList);` fixes it and replacing `(e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey())` with `Map.Entry.comparingByKey()` compensates for the added verbosity…

Comment: @Holger I feel stupid now, cause I wanted to add almost the same thing as an answer...

Comment: I encountered same bug when replacing `() -> Collections.emptyList()` with `Collections::emptyList`and was unable to prepare simple example. It was surprising that replacing Supplier with equivalent method reference doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `javac 8` as it compiles just fine with `javac-9` (with the latest build) - I just can't find it and *I really really tried to*.

Almost as usual adding more type information fixes such things... Also notice that I've changed your `Comparator` to `Comparator.comparingInt...`:

```
 return entrySet.stream().sorted(
            Comparator.comparingInt(Entry::getKey)).collect(
                    Collectors::<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> toList);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise you add more type info to method references. This worked! :)